# Date time convert and retain blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a column value to datetime.

CONVERT(datetime, ColName,105)

This converts all the blank values to default 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.
I want to retain the blank values post conversion too.

Comment: There are no "blank" dates just as there are no blank numbers. I suspect the date was stored in a text field (*very bad* idea) and missing dates are stored as empty spaces instead of NULLs (**very** bad idea). This means you have to reverse two bugs - first check for missing values and then parse the string into a date. The problem is, *what* date do you expect? You can only have an actual `datetime` or a `NULL`.

Comment: You could use `IIF(TRIM(ColName)='', NULL,CONVERT(datetime, ColName,105))` to return a NULL if the column is empty

Comment: Another option is to use `TRY_PARSE` instead of `CONVERT`. `select try_parse( '13-11-2018' as datetime USING 'it')` will return NULL if the value is empty or can't be parsed using the specified culture, the actual date otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If ColName only contains empty (var)char values, you can add NULLIF to the ColName like

```
CONVERT(datetime, NULLIF(ColName, ''),105)
```

Comment: In this case, when ColName is '', the final result should be NULL. Handling the NULL values in whatever default you want if you wrap the CONVERT function.
As you sad in the comment above, you will have a datetime or a NULL

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting to a DATETIME then you won't be able to have a "blank" value, but you could have NULLs instead:

```
CASE WHEN ColName IS NULL OR LEN(LTRIM(ColName)) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, ColName, 105) END
```

This will convert any NULLs, blank strings, or whitespace to a NULL DATETIME, and convert everything else to a DATETIME with a value (assuming it's a valid date).

Answer (score 0):

Blanks values will convert to SQL server default datetime value. Following query will help you not to convert the blank values. However it is better to have NULL instead of a ' '

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NULLIF(COLUMN,'') = NULL THEN 
            NULL 
      ELSE CONVERT(datetime, dd,105) END 
FROM <TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, storing dates as strings and using empty strings to represent missing values are very bad ideas. The problem can be fixed once and for all by converting that field into a nullable `date` or `datetime`.

Until that's done, or in order to do it easily, you can use the [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function available on all supported SQL Server versions. The earliest supported SQL Server version is 2012. 105 is the italian format, so :

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(ColName as datetime USING 'it')
```

For example

```
select try_parse( '13-11-2018' as datetime USING 'it')
```

Will parse the string value into a `datetime` whose value is `2018-11-13 00:00:00.000`. Anything that can't be parsed will return a NULL :

```
select try_parse( '' as datetime USING 'it')
```

Will return `NULL`.

In earlier versions one can use `CASE WHEN` or the equivalent `IIF` :

```
select IIF(TRIM(ColName)='',NULL,CONVERT(datetime, ColName,105))
```

Returning NULL is the only option because date types like `date`, `datetime` etc are scalar types just like `int` or `decimal`. There's no empty date or datetime. The only possibility is to have a NULL for a missing value or an actual date.

Trying to return some kind of blank value means that the dates will have to be converted back to strings.